# Thinly veiled attempt at spam advertising!

Tags: support, spam

The following question is just a thinly veiled attempt at advertising!

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/where-lies-the-future-of-angularjs

Comment: Hard to tell. This is the only committer on the project:  https://github.com/vojtajina. Plus, I'm not sure if Google needs to spam anything they're offering on Programmers SE, but that's just my gut feeling. It's still a closeable question though. Voted to close as NARQ.

Answer (score 1):

Wording smells too much promotional, making reader feel more like at an ad board:

> The javascript framework **a-product** has made a great start. but I am just wondering if this is just another framework like so many already available in javascript. Is **a-product** a competitor of jQuery in a broader sense or can it be compared to lesser known libraies like knockout.js or backbone.js. Do you see yourself moving to **a-product** sometime soon leaving the one that you are already using. I have seen the hello world example on **a-product** page and they compare **a-product** with jquery. Do they mean to say that **a-product** is the future. What is the overall scope of **a-product** in a broader sense and do you see **a-product** replacing jQuery in the longer run.

Deletion of question worded like above would be the right move.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is.

The OP has been a member of Programmers for 8 months, and they seem to be questioning how the framework compares to other javascript frameworks, not raving about its capabilities.

Sure it's badly written and probably should be closed, but I don't think its an advertisement.

> The javascript framework angularjs has made a great start. but I am
>   just **wondering if this is just another framework** like so many
>   already available in javascript. **Is angularjs a competitor of jQuery**
>   in a broader sense **or can it be compared to lesser known libraies**
>   like knockout.js or backbone.js. Do you see yourself moving to
>   angularjs sometime soon leaving the one that you are already using. I
>   have seen the hello world example on anjularjs page and they compare
>   angularjs with jquery. Do they mean to say that angularJS is the
>   future. **What is the overall scope of angularjs** in a broader sense
>   and **do you see angularJs replacing jQuery** in the longer run.